# Null reference exception when using Find on custom object

Tags: c#, .net, object, find, nullreferenceexception

I'm scratching my head a bit here.

I have a custom object which I'm trying to search for a property that starts with some text.

If I search for a property using `==` instead of `StartsWith` it doesn't error.

This works

```
Server serverObject = ServerObjectList.Find(n => n.Name == "Server001");
```

This gives a null ref exception

```
Server serverObject = ServerObjectList.Find(n => n.Name.StartsWith("Server001"));
```

Oddly, it works if the first object is the one your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing like this as n may be null or Name may be null:

```
Server serverObject = ServerObjectList.Find(n => n!=null && n.Name!=null && n.Name.StartsWith("Server001"));
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak. That gets around the null server name I hadn't spotted.

Comment: Welcome. I am glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

your "ServerObjectList" list might be empty. At first it might be evaluating null == "" which gives false. in second statement, you are calling StartsWith function on a null, which gives you nullrefrenceexception. check if the list already has data.

Note: == operator is overloaded for strings. This might be doing null check before returning false.

Comment: Yeah I already checked and my ServerObjectList is full of objects.

Comment: ok, does every object has Name property not null?

Comment: Yep, all objects in he list have a name property. Non are null or empty.

Comment: Ah, I just found a server with no name. Didn't see it at first.

Comment: Yes, you can update your code to check nulls.